# XPages: what is the lifetime of an application scope variable?

Tags: xpages, scope, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

A. What is the actual lifetime of an application scope variable in xpages?

B. how can i remove/reset it if necessary? 
(I can't find anything like "re-deploy" or "start-stop application", so do i have to restart the webserver,do it with code, just re-save my application from designer or anything else...?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A. It varies. You can set an explicit timeout in the XSP Properties (surfaced in Designer 9 as a design element under the Application Configuration category; in 8.5.x you'll need to navigate to WebContent/WEB-INF/xsp.properties via Package Explorer). Otherwise, it times out when Domino thinks it "should". This is based on application usage, so the more heavily the app is used, the less likely the scope will ever expire unless the HTTP task -- or Domino itself -- is restarted.

B. To destroy the entire scope, restart HTTP (or restart Domino entirely). **NOTE:** this is *not*

`Tell HTTP Restart`

...which only reloads certain portions of the task, and does not reload the JVM. You need to actually restart the task:

```
Tell HTTP Quit
Load HTTP
```

OR

`Restart Task HTTP`

After the task restarts, a fresh application scope will be instantiated the next time the application is accessed.

You can also selectively clean the scope. Each of the scopes in XPages (request / view / session / application) is an instance of a [Java Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html), so each supports all of the methods defined in that interface.

I would recommend only removing specific items, e.g.:

`applicationScope.remove("myBean");`

If you clear the entire scope without actually destroying the scope itself (see above), it can cause unpredictable behavior, because the platform also stores its own information in the application scope (this applies to the other scopes as well). You should only remove scope entries that you added.

Comment: As the Necromancers demand: you keep what you kill paired with the old German saying: Nürnbergians don't kill anybody unless they have him... You should only remove what you added beforehand

Comment: Do you mean `xsp.application.timeout` and does that work for you? I once tested this (I think in 8.5.3 with anonymous user) and my `applicationScope` variable always disappeared in 15 minutes or less. `xsp.application.timeout` had no effect.

Answer (score 5):

As the Name application scope variable already tells you its lifetime is as long as the application is running if defined in the xsp.properties if you defined nothing the standard duration is 30 minutes. or  Or from [IBM](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/xpages-scoped-variables.htm):

> The applicationScope duration is the WebModule duration. A web module is started when the first request comes in, and is eventually discarded after a period of inactivity, the default being 30 minutes. Every user of the application can access these variables once they are created, so there is no privacy with these variables. The applicationScope should only be used for data that must be shared among many XPages.

If you develope using application scope vars you can reset them by clearing your Application in designer go to: Projekt => clear...

or if this does not help try following code from [Tommy Valand](http://dontpanic82.blogspot.co.at/2010/06/xpages-simple-function-to-clear-scoped.html):

```
function clearMap( map:Map ){
 // Get iterator for the keys
 var iterator = map.keySet().iterator();

 // Remove all items
 while( iterator.hasNext() ){
  map.remove( iterator.next() );
 }
}
```

This will allow you to reset the application scope durring runtime, verry usefull for debugging and testing.

Comment: Install the [XPage Debug Toolbar](https://demo.linqed.eu/debugToolbar/debugToolbar.nsf/demoPage.xsp) in your app to easily clear scoped variables while developing. It uses code similar to this.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that refreshing the design also clears application scope variables....